# $_POST array empty even though AJAX POST request came back as 200/ok?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, post

I've looked through several question/answer combinations relating to my issue, but the suggestions I've tried haven't worked.

This is my my AJAX request:

```
$('#submitRequest').on('click', function() {
    // package everything to get it ready for transfer
    var textSamples = JSON.stringify(packTextStyles());
    var swatches = JSON.stringify(packSwatches());
    var clientInfo = JSON.stringify(packClientInfo());

    $.ajax ({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'classes/requestHandler.php',
        //headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        data: {
            typeSamples: textSamples,
            swatchSamples: swatches,
            userInfo: clientInfo
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data === 'added') {
                alert('ok');
            }
            else {
                alert(data);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

The three vars `textSamples`, `swatches`, and `clientInfo` are all arrays. The `textSamples` array contains eight objects with each having five properties, so it's a good chunk of data being sent over. 
My problem is that `var_dump($_POST)` returns an empty array and any attempt at trying `json_decode($_POST['typeSamples'])` gives me an error of undefined index on PHP side.

Here is the screenshot of the headers on the network tab in Chrome dev tools:
[image: Headers from POST]

So $_POST is getting something, but I have no idea where it's going. Some questions:

1. Do I need to put `headers: {'Content-Type':
   'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}` or `headers: {'Content-Type':
   'application/json'}` in the AJAX, since I used `JSON.stringify()`?
2. Because I used AJAX I didn't put `method="post"
   action="something.php"` in the `form` tag, and the `input` tags
   don't have the `name` attributes. `Submit` button doesn't have
   `type="submit"`. Does that matter?

EDIT: If it matters, I'm using jQuery 1.11.1 and PHP 5.4.12

EDIT2: half-finished PHP:

```
<?php


$reqGetter = new RequestReceiver;
$reqGetter->checkInput();


class RequestReceiver{
    // public function __construct() {
    //  $textSamples = json_decode($_POST['typeSamples']);
    // }
    public function checkInput() {

        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            echo('added');
            $typeSamples = json_decode($_POST['typeSamples'], true);
            print_r($typeSamples);
        } else {
            echo('failed');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a PHP framework, or just your own PHP files?

Comment: My own. Should I not be? Or is it a matter of verifying what PHP is receiving in $_POST?

Comment: I only asked because some frameworks might clear out $_POST in favor of accessing that data using their own methods/classes.

Comment: If you want to use `$_POST` in your PHP, stick with the jQuery default content-type (application/x-www-form-urlencoded). Your code looks fine to me

Comment: Is jQuery's type parameter case sensitive? e.g. `POST` vs `post`?

Comment: @scrowler you wouldn't think so but it's worth a shot

Comment: @scrowler I tried capping it last night, but I'll try again to make sure

Comment: No difference between `type: 'POST'` and `type: 'post'`

Comment: Try doing a var_dump on $_GET, $_POST and $_REQUEST. Then you will know exactly everything you are receiving.

Comment: I think we're going to need to see the PHP file accepting the POST request as that's obviously where the problem is. Any chance you could add the full set of response headers too?

Comment: Wait, why is there an `Origin` header present? That should only show up for a CORS request

Comment: I just looked at the "response" tab in Chrome > Dev Tools > Network and it now works. I was just going to the page myself, so of course the $_POST array would be empty. I need to sleep.

Comment: @NojoRu but why does it say `Content-Length: 5` in the response (in your screenshot)? There's obviously way more than 5 bytes of POST data

Comment: I have no idea, @Phil, but now it says 1841

Comment: Voting to close as **a problem that can no longer be reproduced**.

Comment: @Phil, seconded. Thank you, everyone, for your help. The response tab definitely helped, so whomever suggested that (I can't find it now), thank you!